# Nature of roots of a biquadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, graphing-functions, irreducible-polynomials

*(Biquadratic $\rightarrow$ Quartic (degree 4))*

**The Question:** (*from a book i am practicing from*)

Find the nature of the roots of the equation $$f(x) = 45 x^4-144 x^3+146 x^2-56 x+12=0$$

(*By nature i mean...Real/Imaginary*)

---

**My attempt:**

Well my first attempt was *knowing at least one root by Hit-and-Trial*. So that it is of the form $$f(x)=(x-\alpha)(ax^3+bx^2+cx+d)=0$$

And then I would have solved the cubic the same way and finally having $$(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)(x-\delta)=0$$

But Hit-and-Trial doesn't seem to work here.

---

**Next attempt:**

I tried raw graphing of the function by using *maxima/minima*.

I differentiated $f(x)$ to get $$f'(x)=45x^3-108x^2+73x-14$$

I did $f'(x)=0$ and Thought I would arrive at some values of $x$ resulting in a graph like :

[image: 1]

But I couldn't as I could not even solve this cubic equation!

---

> **So how should I solve this problem? Please also help me about drawing the graph of a biquadratic equation. *Thanks***

---

**P.S.** - Here is a link to wolfram alpha for this equation : http://goo.gl/zs4zDa [It also has the roots as $1.1718,1.5671,0.23-0.3i,0.23+0.3i$]

---

**EDIT** - Please do not think that I will be able to guess $1.1718$ while solving the quadratic or $\frac{1}{3}$ while solving its derivative (the cubic)! Also I want to ask this question for a general biquadratic equation where all roots *may not be real*. So no Easy Guesses!! In some cases the roots may be like $\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}$ or something like $2-3i$.

Comment: You're not meant to find the roots explicitly. All you need to do is show that there is at least one real and one complex root. Then you know there is another complex conjugate and another real root. This gives a total of 2 complex and 2 real roots.

Comment: @ZainPatel Ya i know...that's why i was also trying to do it graphically...BTW thanks for the 'complex conjugate' idea! I had forgotten it

Comment: There is no biquadratic equation here, as there are cubic and linear terms.

Comment: The general method for solving such equations is quite complicated, you don't want to go there.

Comment: @Axel I DONT want to go there! Just tell me how to solve this problem without finding out the roots

Comment: Well I think @ZainPatel 's answer is valid.

Comment: @Axel Read the comments below his answer...*not valid*!

Comment: Nickalls has some good papers with methods for dealing with the quartic equation:
http://nickalls.org/dick/papers/maths/quartic2009.pdf
http://nickalls.org/dick/papers/maths/tetrahedron2012.pdf He also has an excellent paper on the geometric interpretation of the cubic in that same directory.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of your quartic is $$4(45x^3 - 108x^2 + 73x - 14) = 4(3x-2)(3x-1)(5x-7)$$

So the stationary points are at $x = \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{7}{5}$, does this help you draw the graph?

In addition to this, we have the second derivative as $$540x^2-864x + 292$$
that will allow you to check whether your stationary points are minimums or maximums.

[image]

Comment: how did you factorize the cubic eq.? Also the whole point of this question is for how to deal with a situation where it is NON-factorizable. The eq i gave is just an example...

Comment: The quartic is non-factorizable, but it's derivative is factorisable. You do hit-and-trial to guess one root and then divide the cubic by $x- \frac{1}{3}$ to get a quadratic that you can solve using the quad. formula for the other two stationary points.

Comment: How am i supposed to guess $\frac{1}{3}$ ? Or for example if the root is $\frac{21}{22}$...What am i  gonna do then?

Comment: Have you heard of the rational roots theorem?

Comment: Ya...But I don't think the roots are always rational....

Comment: In that case, you'll have to resort to numerical methods like interval bisection.